# Files left after formatting

Tags: applications, factory-reset

I factory reset my android phone. When I saw the log after formatting(yet no app installed), I was getting

```
Processing Container com.mapswithme.maps.pro
Container com.mapswithme.maps.pro-1 slate
..
..
```

and for other apps that i earlier installed. Why is android looking for it after i format the phone. If these files still exist on phone how to remove them. My phone is NOT rooted. {and i intend to keep it that way}. the apps are in mnt/secure/asec

any possible solution ?????

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two relevant facts.

1. Apps that were pre-installed as part of the system (i.e. came with the phone) are not deleted by a factory reset: they just go back to the original version, and will probably be updated by Google Play later.
2. If you had **Back up my data** turned on in the device settings (on the **Backup & reset** page), then as soon as you signed into your Google account, the phone will have started to reinstall all the apps you had installed previously, and the data of all the apps that support Google backup.

Comment: pre-installed app are in system/app but the above mentioned app are in mnt/secure/asec